# Java - regex on sql query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, regex, hibernate

I need to apply a **java regex** on sql query string to calculate the **count** of it. I have to get what is between the "**first select**" and "**from**" of the principal query. 
This is my example : 
**Query :**
`select name,(select age from subtable), adress from table where name in (select name from subtable1)`
**Result** :
`select count(*) from table where name in (select name from subtable1)`

I was using `replaceFirst("^(.*?)from", "select count(*) from")` but it is not working because there is an sql query in the attribute.

Please anyone can help ?

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct approach? I feel an XY problem here.

Comment: @Thomas, I need to get the count of the query without executing the original one, it is just a performance problem. If you have another approach, I'm all ears, thanks.

Comment: What kind of performance problems do you want to solve? In most cases really executing the query should provide the best information especially since you could do the count on the results. Any alteration of the query is likely to falsify the information anyways. So if you're after a general indicator on query performance wouldn't a simple `EXPLAIN <query>` be sufficient? And since you've also added the hibernate tag: AFAIK Hibernate can collect a bunch of statistics that might help as well.

Comment: @Thomas, I need to get only the count information which will be used for pagination. Executing the whole query (20 attributes or more) is really expensive. All I want is to get the count directly by altering the query.

Comment: what about `from table` like this `str.replaceFirst("^(.*?)from table", "select count(*) from table");` ?

Comment: @YCF_L "table" is just an example, the tables name is dynamic.

Comment: If it's for pagination it might be safer to dynamically build 2 queries with the same from clause (we're using a similar approach). Alternatively, some databases support returning the count of the query even if you just load a page (via offset and limit) thus it could be done in one query. Altering queries using regular expressions is very risky imo.

Comment: I agree @Thomas but I have dynamic queries, there is no possible way to get the count without using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using this regex `^(.*?)from(?![^(]*\\))`:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^(.*?)from(?![^(]*\\))", "select count(*) from");
```

**Output**

```
select count(*) from table where name in (select name from subtable1)
```

The idea is match `from` that is inside `()` parenthesis.

---

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/fMR3al)